# Permanently disable Project > Build Automatically in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse

Every time I open Eclipse I have to turn this off. I would think this would just persist through an application restart but it isn't for me. Is there a setting I am missing?

Comment: I just tried unchecking the Project => Build Automatically option, closed and reopened Eclipse, and the option was still unchecked for me. I have neon.3. Are you toggling that option some other way?

Comment: @PaulT. Not to my knowledge. I've looked around in workspace settings and the build automatically checkbox is in fact unchecked in there. I'm running oxygen.1

Comment: @PaulT. my eclipse.ini has -clean at the top, I'm wondering if that is resetting auto build on startup each time...

Comment: I'm not sure. I tried a Project => Clean, but the option remains unchecked. I'll have to see what is in my ini file.

Comment: I added the `-clean` to the top of my `eclipse.ini` file, but the Build Automatically option that I toggled for the project remains unchecked. I did see the other option in settings that you mentioned (`Window => Preferences => General => Workspace`). I wonder if option in settings applies to new projects, and the `Project => Build Automatically` option can be toggled on a project by project basis?